# How to compute $\int_0^1x^a(1-x)^be^{cx}dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

> How to compute the integral $I(a,b,c) = \int_0^1x^a(1-x)^be^{cx}dx$ ?

I know that,
$\int_0^1{x^a(1-x)^b}dx = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+2)}$. Using this result, I tried integration by parts; I got the following recurrence relation,

$I(a,b,c) = \frac{b}{c}I(a,b-1,c) - \frac{a}{c}I(a-1,b,c)$.

I don't know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Series expanding $e^{cx}$ is one option. This leads to something like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{c^n}{n!} \frac{\Gamma(a+n+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+n+2)}$ which looks like some sort of hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This is essentially the the moment generating function of the beta distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Moment_generating_function) The result is hypergeometric and cannot be further simplified.